# Depict legend without repeats

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to add a colored legend to a Matplotlib scatterplot. Here's my code:

```
xs = [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2]
ys = [1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1]
labels = [1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3]

label_dict = {0: 'r', 1: 'k', 2: 'b', 3: 'g'}
legend_dict = {0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', 2: 'baz', 3: 'biff'}

for x, y, label in zip(xs, ys, labels):
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=label_dict.get(label), label=legend_dict.get(label))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I get the legend to only display one label for each color instead of a label for each point?

Comment: Have you looked at http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html?  I'm not sure if that gives you what you need, but the first few lines seem to provide access to the legend.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at this reference as well as many others. I'm still baffled as to how to create a simple scatterplot legend with one label for all points with the same color.

Comment: Duplicated from a question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607545/depict-legend-without-repeats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep track of which labels you've seen:

```
import pylab as plt

xs = [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2]
ys = [1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1]
labels = [1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3]

label_dict = {0: 'r', 1: 'k', 2: 'b', 3: 'g'}
legend_dict = {0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', 2: 'baz', 3: 'biff'}

seen = set()
for x, y, label in zip(xs, ys, labels):
    if label not in seen:
        plt.scatter(x, y, c=label_dict.get(label), label=legend_dict.get(label))
    else:
        plt.scatter(x, y, c=label_dict.get(label))
    seen.add(label)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The if/else clause could be condensed into 1 line if you'd rather:

```
seen = set()
for x, y, label in zip(xs, ys, labels):
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=label_dict.get(label), label=legend_dict.get(label) if label not in seen else None)
    seen.add(label)
```

---

I think that I would personally prefer to keep the data grouped.  In other words, I'd probably store all of the data with the same label together, then you only need to issue one `plot` command per label type:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

xs = [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2]
ys = [1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1]
labels = [1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3]

xs = np.array(xs)
ys = np.array(ys)
labels = np.array(labels)

labels_masks =( (x,(labels == x)) for x in set(labels))
data_dict = dict( (lbl,(xs[mask],ys[mask])) for lbl,mask in labels_masks )


label_dict = {0: 'r', 1: 'k', 2: 'b', 3: 'g'}
legend_dict = {0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', 2: 'baz', 3: 'biff'}

for label,data in data_dict.items():
    x,y = data
    plt.scatter(x,y,c=label_dict.get(label),label=legend_dict.get(label))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Many many thanks. I've always struggled with how to do colored legends with scatter plots. It definitely seems the API was designed for the "grouped" approach. Thanks for pointing that out to me.